# shopify price rules api , how to get only active discounts?

Tags: node.js, api, shopify, shopify-app, shopify-activemerchant

I'm working on a Shopify app using node js, and I need to get the list of discounts from merchants store, so I used the price rules admin API to get the list, but the problem is I'm getting all the discounts even inactive or expired discounts , can anyone help me to filter this , I searched a lot on Shopify documentation but I did not found any solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "ends_at_min" param and set today's date (format 2017-03-25T16:15:47-04:00) in its value to get the active discounts only. Please check for the

Thanks

Comment: thanks , yes but in this case, i will get the only discount with an end time, if a discount is open so it will not be listed, also deactivated discount will be listed

Comment: can you share the enpoint url to search and filter the price rule api. I am unable to search price rule api based on title...